# PHP Concatenating strings to be used in SQL queries

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, concatenation

Let's say i have 6 variables which are all strings. and i want to make them into one long string.

However i only want to put the part that are not equal to "*" in.
For example:

```
    $x = $_POST["x"]; ($x = "abcde")
    $y = $_POST["y"]; ($y = "fghijk")
    $z = $_POST["z"]; ($z = "lmnop")
    $a = $_POST["a"]; ($a = "*")
    $b = $_POST["b"]; ($b = "qrstu")
    $c = $_POST["c"]; ($c = "vwxyz")
    Wanted Output:
    $alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    Solution i want to have
    $alpha = if($a !="*"){$a}else{""}.
             if($b !="*"){$b}else{""}.
             if($c !="*"){$c}else{""}.
             if($d !="*"){$d}else{""}.
             if($e !="*"){$e}else{""}.
             if($f !="*"){$f}else{""}
```

I'm pretty sure using '.' concatenates the multiple statements.

But i dont know how to properly piece them into a string which can be used in

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$aplha);
```

The variables $x,$y,$z,$a,$b,$c can all be "*" on an occasion. which is why i want to filter them out if they're an asterisk.

(i know "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" isnt a proper query. i'm just substituting in letters for sections of a query i want to have. and i want certain parts to not be in the query depending on what the value is)

in short. how do i concatenate the above statements leaving parts out when a variable = "*"

Comment: Why don't you concatenate all the variables and then delete the * string using str_replace?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate strings with short hand if/else logic or the ternary operator.

```
 $alpha =   ($a =="*" ? "" : $a) .
            ($b =="*" ? "" : $b) .
            ($c =="*" ? "" : $c) .
            ($d =="*" ? "" : $d) .
            ($e =="*" ? "" : $e) .
            ($f =="*" ? "" : $f) ;
```

You can find detailed example for ternary operator [here](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).